# Help reg to write gawk script

Tags: gawk

Need sample gawk to join two records with unique key $2.$1 has different entity eventhough $2 is key thats why there are ther are two different lines for same key

I/p FIle not in sorted order

01|12345|AAAA
01|99|AAAA
01|888|AAAA
02|12345|BBBBB|CCCCC|DDDDD
02|99|BBBBB|CCCCC|DDDDD
02|888|BBBBB|CCCCC|DDDDD

Output file:

O/p file
01|12345|DDDDD
01|99|DDDDD
01|888||DDDDD

Comment: This is quite unclear. If the key is unique, why are there multiple records with that key? What exactly is the transformation rule you want to apply?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with `awk`, e.g. like this:

```
awk '
    BEGIN { FS=OFS="|" }
    $2!=old { print sav ; sav=$0 ; old=$2 ; next }
    { sub(/[^|]*\|[^|]*\|/,"") ; sav=sav OFS $0 }
    END { print sav }
'
```

Comment: Thanks this help, added to the first request if the input is not sorted and expecting the o/p in diff way
I/p FIle
01|12345|AAAA
01|99|AAAA
01|888|AAAA
02|12345|BBBBB|CCCCC|DDDDD
02|99|BBBBB|CCCCC|DDDDD
02|888|BBBBB|CCCCC|DDDDD

O/p file
01|12345|DDDDD
01|99|DDDDD
01|888|DDDDD